# TCP client doesn't receive back server's messages

Tags: android, python, sockets, tcp

I have python server serving multiple android clients over TCP connections. The clients successfully connect to and send messages to the server, but they fail to receive the server's response (if it was sth other than echoing the original message they sent).
The blocking `mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();` on the client side keeps blocking for ever failing to capture the server's reply. I can't understand what's it that I am doing wrong.
Server Code:

```
import socket
import thread
import time

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.105'
TCP_PORT = 5004

BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response
NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS = 2

def on_new_client(clientsocket,addr):
    while True:
        msg = clientsocket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) 
        if not msg: break
        print addr, ' >> ', msg, '\n'
        #msg = raw_input('SERVER >> ')
        clientsocket.send(msg) #If I sent anything other than the original message (for example: clientsocket.send(bytes("ss")) or clientsocket.send("ss")) the client fails to capture it!!

    clientsocket.close()


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


print 'Server started!'
print 'Waiting for clients...'

s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS) 


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept() # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    thread.start_new_thread(on_new_client,(conn,addr))

s.close()
```

Client code:

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(home.SERVER_IP);

Log.i("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

//create a socket to make the connection with the server
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_REQUESTS_PORT);

try {

    //sends the message to the server
    mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

    //receives the message which the server sends back -> the number of clients remaining
    mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    Log.i("tcpClient", "mBufferIN" + String.valueOf(mBufferIn));

    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
    //home.remainingCount.setText(mServerMessage);
    Log.i("tcpClient", "mBufferIN = " + mServerMessage); //This is never excuted when the message 
    counterValueRetrieved = true;

    while (mRun) {


        if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
            //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
            mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
        }

    }

    Log.i("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

} catch (Exception e) {

    Log.i("TCP", "S: Error", e);

} finally {
    //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
    // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
    socket.close();
}

} catch (Exception e) {

Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

}
```

note  that

```
// used to send messages
private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
// used to read messages from the server
private BufferedReader mBufferIn;
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clients try to read lines. Lines are strings that end on \n.

```
clientsocket.send(bytes("ss"))
```

So you should send a line:

```
clientsocket.send(bytes("ss\n"))
```